# same data appear in whole recylerview

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview

same data appear in whole Recyclerview and position increasing but data same appear

in useradapter i log the position and position increase but data is same in onbindviewholder

useradapter

```
public class useradapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<useradapter.CustomView> {

String nn = "m";

List<allusermodel> list1;
private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


public useradapter(Context context, List<allusermodel> list1) {
    Log.e("reached1", nn);
    this.context = context;
    this.list1 = list1;

}


@Override
public useradapter.CustomView onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {

    Log.e("reached2", nn);
    if (layoutInflater == null) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    }

    final Entrys newsBinding = Entrys.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false);


    //  View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.innerlayout,parent,false);
    return new CustomView(newsBinding);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(useradapter.CustomView holder,int position) {
    Log.e("reached3", nn);

    //  News news = newsList.get(position);

    // holder.desc.setText(news.getDesc());

     allusermodel newsModel1 = list1.get(position);
   // Log.e("list", String.valueOf(list1));
    Log.e("nameeeee",newsModel1.getAll_user());
   // Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));

    //Log.e("names",newsModel1.getAll_user());
    holder.bind(newsModel1);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list1.size();

}

public class CustomView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private Entrys newsBinding;
   // public TextView title;

     //TextView title, desc;
    public CustomView(Entrys newsBinding) {
        super(newsBinding.getRoot());

        this.newsBinding = newsBinding;
        Log.e("reached4", nn);
       // title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleval);
        //desc =(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.descval);
        newsBinding.setRecyclerclick(new Presenters2() {
            @Override
            public void onclickListener() {

                int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                if (pos != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                    allusermodel clickedDataItem = list1.get(pos);

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, messagelist.class);
                    intent.putExtra("clickid", clickedDataItem.getId());

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public void bind(allusermodel newsModel1)

    {
        Log.e("reached5", String.valueOf(newsModel1));
        //String j = newsModel1.getAll_user();
        // Log.e("bind",nn);
        this.newsBinding.setAlluserentry(newsModel1);
    }


    public Entrys getNewsBinding() {
        Log.e("reached6", nn);
        return newsBinding;
    }

}
}
```

userlist

```
public class userlist extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "userlist";

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
private DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration;
private useradapter customAdapter;
private DataManager2 dataManger;
private List<allusermodel> newsList;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

String token2;
String URL1 = "https://chat.promactinfo.com/api/user";

private int userid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userlist);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    token2 = pref.getString("sherdtoken", "");
    Log.e("token", token2);

    dataManger = new DataManager2(this);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycle);
    /*recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    newsList = new ArrayList<>();

    customAdapter = new useradapter(this, newsList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(customAdapter);*/

    newsList = new ArrayList<>();


    getdata();
}

public void getdata() {



    dataManger.sendVolleyRequest1(token2, userlist.this, new DataValue() {

        @Override
        public void setJsonDataResponse1(JSONArray response) {

            allusermodel userModel = new allusermodel();
           // newsList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {


                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                   // Log.e("final", String.valueOf(i));
                  //  userid = jsonObject.getInt("id");
                    userModel.setId(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                  //  Log.e("getid", String.valueOf(jsonObject.getInt("id")));
                    userModel.setAll_user(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                   // Log.e("getname", String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString("name")));

                    newsList.add(userModel);
                  //  Log.e("userlist", String.valueOf(newsList));



                } catch (JSONException jsonDataResponse) {
                    Log.e("error", String.valueOf(jsonDataResponse));

                }
            }
            adapter = new useradapter(getApplicationContext(),newsList);

            linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
            linearLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            dividerItemDecoration = new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), linearLayoutManager.getOrientation());

            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
            recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public void setVolleyError1(VolleyError volleyError) {
            Log.e("Volley", volleyError.toString());
        }
    });


}
}
```

allusermodel

```
public class allusermodel extends BaseObservable {


public int id;
public String all_user;


public allusermodel() {
}

public allusermodel(int id,String name ) {


    this.id = id;
    this.all_user = name;


}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAll_user() {
    return all_user;
}

public void setAll_user(String all_user) {
    this.all_user = all_user;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "allusermodel{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", all_user='" + all_user + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

userlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.userlist"
android:orientation="vertical">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:id="@+id/recycle"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

innerlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data class ="Entrys">
    <variable
        name="alluserentry"

type="com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.viewmodel.allusermodel"/>

    <variable
        name="recyclerclick"

type="com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.interfaces.Presenters2"/>

</data>


<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:padding="10dp"
android:onClick="@{()->recyclerclick.onclickListener()}"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/titleval"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:text="@{alluserentry.all_user}"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
   />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

whole recyclerview have same data which i previous add in api 
(if i enter name in entry then it show previous entry in whole recylerview
ane then if i enter name1 in entry then it show name in whole recylerview )

Comment: no need to call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged because you have already created new object of adapter with new list. and please check your response object  first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems, the issue is coming because you have created the Model object outside the for loop when you are populating the data from sever. As a result the last value in the list will show to all the RecyclerView items.

Now the solution is that you create the model inside the "for-loop" as a first statement.

```
public void getdata() {

dataManger.sendVolleyRequest1(token2, userlist.this, new DataValue() {

    @Override
    public void setJsonDataResponse1(JSONArray response) {

       //allusermodel userModel = new allusermodel();
       // newsList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
            allusermodel userModel = new allusermodel();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
```

I hope it will resolve your issue.

Comment: thanks it's working now, one more thing when i click recyclerview it goes to messagelist but it actually goes to mainactivity why this happen

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm, PID: 21181
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm/com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.messagelist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.databinding.ActivityMessagelistBinding cannot be cast to com.example.mayurpancholi.chat_mvvm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

Comment: Create a class variable as "private Activity context;" in userlist activiy and in onCreate assign the value to it after setContentView() such as "context = this;" Once it is done, pass this context to adpter constructor instead of getApplicationContext() in getdata() method. So the construction calling will be "adapter = new useradapter(context, newsList);" Also make sure you have declared the userlist activity in Manifest.java. Please check and let me know if it worked.

Comment: that's right when i click the text in recyclerview then it will open messagelist activity and it open messagelist activity then app crashed and show the data binding error(which is above mention) so please check the code at https://github.com/pmayur1998/chat_mvvm and userlist ,messagelist is declared in activity manifest.java,  by the way thank you for your sudden reply